# Como imprimir corretamente caracteres acentuados em arquivo?

Tags: perl

Estou fazendo um programa que precisa obter as palavras em um arquivo que tem uma determinada formatação. Está tudo funcionando corretamente exceto que, no arquivo de saída, os caracteres acentuados ficam errados. Inclusive inseri duas linhas de debug pra printar no console a palavra encontrada e, nesse caso, os caracteres acentuados aparecem corretamente. Eu acredito que existe algum problema de codificação mas não sei o que é.

A saída no arquivo fica assim: (as coisas esquisitas são as letras acentuadas)

abdala

abdelcÃ¡der

abdelcÃ¡dir

achÃªmenes

adÃ³nide

Código:

```
while (<$in>){
if ($_ =~ /& .*/){ # Testa se a linha tem o formato de interesse.
    my @linha = split (//, $_);
    my $count = 0;

    # Obtém o início da palavra.
    while ($linha[$count] !~ /[a-zA-Záéíóúãẽĩõũâêîôûàèìòùäëïöü]/) { $count++; } 
    my $inicio = $count;

    # Obtém o fim da palavra e calcula o tamanho.
    while ($linha[$count] =~ /[a-zA-ZáéíóúãẽĩõũâêîôûàèìòùäëïöüÁÉÍÓÚÃẼĨÕŨÂÊÎÔÛÀÈÌÒÙÄËÏÖÜ]/) { $count++; }
    my $tamanho = $count - $inicio;         

    # Obtém a palavra em caixa baixa e grava no arquivo.
    my $palavra = lc (substr ($_, $inicio, $tamanho));
    print $out "$palavra\n";

    print $palavra; #DEBUG
    print "\n"; #DEBUG
}
}
```

Comment: tenta juntar `use utf8::all;` no início...

Comment: Coloque um exemplo do arquivo de entrada, e descubra o formato do arquivo de entrada com o comando `file arquivo`